# regular expression to remove all tags with content and html code from a string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am looking to develop a regular expression which remove all html tags with the names , script tags, all content in the script tag (basically all javascript code), and any html code 
like   etc just no html or javascript code in the the string should pass.
Update:

I think the questioned was not so clear may be this should be more clear.

i want the `'<' and '>'` to be NOT allowed in the string along with any special characters like `;,# ...` etc. I dont care if there is a tag like `"<html>" or "<body> "`etc" I just want to return false so that user cannot enter any tag at all, also I want to block all javascript so I am assuming if I dont allow the `<,>` the script tag wont pass and js code wont pass?

So the regex should just not allow inclusion of any <, > and other special charaters like `;#@$%& etc` so that other html code apart from tags is also blocked ... e.g `&nbsp;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: You want all the text nodes concatenated together except for `script` elements?

Comment: i want not '<'  and '>' to be allowed in the string also any special characters like ;,# I dont care if there is a tag like "<html>" I just want to return false so that user cannot enter any tag at all, also  Iwant to block all javascript so I am assuming if I dont allow the <,> the script tag wont pass and js code wont pass?

Answer (score 1):

For validating if an HTML element or a String contains HTML tags, check the following JavaScript function :

```
function containsHTMLTags(str)
{
        if(str.match(/([\<])([^\>]{1,})*([\>])/i)==null)
         return false;
        else
         return true;
}
```

The function uses black-list filtering.

References : http://www.hscripts.com/scripts/JavaScript/html-tag-validation.php

Comment: `escape("<") == '%3C'` and not `&lt;`. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.escape

Comment: Thanks, this is good start but I dont want to process any input contains illegal character, I will just return false instead of correcting it, I want to force the user to correct himself.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[^<>;#]*$
```

if string matches that regex it doesn't contains the characters in brackets. I hope I understand your question well.

Comment: This regex looks promising and I will be trying to match it and test it . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a regular expression for that.

You can't use `textContent` or `innerText` because at least the former returns the body of `script` elements.

If I was only supporting newer browsers and had access to (or *shimmed*) `Array.prototype.indexOf()`, `Array.prototype.reduce()` and `Array.prototype.map()`, here is what I might use...

```
var getText = function me(node, excludeElements) {

    if (!excludeElements instanceof Array) {
        excludeElements = [];
    } else {
        excludeElements.map(function(element) {
            return element.toLowerCase();
        });
    }

    return [].slice.call(node.childNodes).reduce(function(str, node) {
        var nodeType = node.nodeType;
        switch (nodeType) {
        case 3:
            return str + node.data;
        case 1:
            if (excludeElements.indexOf(node.tagName.toLowerCase()) == -1) {
                return str + me(node, excludeElements);
            }
        }
        return '';
    }, '');

}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LnKqa/).

Answer (score 0):

Regex.Replace(html, @"]*>[\s\S]*?|<[^>]+>", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Trim();

here html is a string having the html of a page from which it need to remove html and script tags